# Как собрать приложение PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

столкнулся с проблемой о том что моё приложение на PyQt5 имеет вот такую структуру

main.py

```
class Hello(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Hello, self).__init__()
        loadUi("hello.ui", self)

class settingss(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(settingss, self).__init__()
        loadUi("settings.ui", self)
```

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    welcome = Hello()
    widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    widget.setWindowTitle('hey ikon')
    widget.setWindowIcon(QIcon('logo.png'))
    widget.addWidget(welcome)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

и имеет множество файлов

```
hello.ui
setting.ui
****.ui
****.ui
и т.д
```

то есть классическое управление через один файлик main.py который открывает другие окна .ui
И когда я собираю exe с помощью pyinstaller приложение не открывается

Comment: а что пишет, когда приложение не открывается ? должны же быть какие-то сообщения об ошибке

Comment: Да просто консоль на несколько милисекунд открывается и все

Comment: Ошибок не при сборке нигде нет

Comment: попробуйте запустить не из Проводника, а из консоли ваш `.exe`, может тогда увидете какие-то сообщения об ошибке

Comment: OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI60762\coincurve\libsecp256k1.dll': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI60762\\coincurve\\libsecp256k1.dll'